# iPad still asking for passwords on free software even after I've turned it off

Tags: ios-appstore, ipados

I have "require password for free downloads" turned **off**, yet for some reason it still asks me for the password.

My iPad 10 is running iOS 16.2.

I've tried

- signing in and out of iCloud,
- restarting,
- toggling the setting on and off.

Whenever I try to **download a free app**, I still have to put in my mom's password. Is my iPad broken?

Answer (score 1):

Does the device have Touch ID enabled for App Store purchases, and you're choosing to not use Touch ID to authorise the free purchase? You will then be prompted for the password.

> If you have enabled Touch ID or Face ID for App Store and iTunes Store purchases, you'll be asked to use Touch ID or Face ID for every download, even if the item is free.

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204030